# Bash process substitution backgrounding with job control

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, multiprocessing, process-substitution

I have a script which processes a batch of 20MiB CSV files, optionally gzip-compressed down to about 4MiB. There are many thousands of files and processing each individually takes about 30 seconds; reading either an uncompressed file or else a compressed file and decompressing is "almost instant", highly suggesting that the process can be parallelized on the process level. Indeed, that's what's being done using a complex Ruby pipeline. However, I'm attempting to break the Ruby code into smaller parts using bash. For job control, I'd come up with this bash function

```
wait_until_job_available() {
    maximum_jobs=${MAXIMUM_JOBS}
    [ $# -eq 0 ] || maximum_jobs="${1}"
    exit_status=0
    RUNNING_JOBS=( $(jobs -p) )
    while [ ${maximum_jobs} -le ${#RUNNING_JOBS[@]} ] && [ 0 -eq "${exit_status}" ]
    do
        # `wait -n` requires bash 4.3 which is unfortunately not available on several recent RHEL-based Linux distributions such as Oracle Linux
        wait -n
        exit_status=$?
        RUNNING_JOBS=( $(jobs -p) )
    done
    return ${exit_status}
}
```

This allows me to call `wait_until_job_available`, with an optional minimum number of running jobs allowed (if omitted, it defaults to the number of cores available on the machine), prior to backgrounding a bash pipeline.

So I might use it, like such:

```
while read file
do
    CAT_COMMAND=cat

    # if input file is gzip-compressed, pipe zcat instead of cat
    if [ "${INFILE: -3}" == ".gz" ]
    then
        CAT_COMMAND=zcat
    fi

    # wait for a job to become available
    wait_until_job_available

    # read the uncompressed file, write processed data to file.out
    process_file -i <(${CAT_COMMAND} ${file}) -o ${file}.out &

# while searching for filesystem paths of type _f_ile
done < <(find ${search_path} -type f)

# wait for all background jobs to finish
wait
```

As you can see, this should find all files within `search_path` and pass that to the `process_file` command. In doing so, I use process substitution to either cat the file or else decompress the file on-the-fly; the input filename gets substituted with a process which will emit the contents of the uncompressed file, and the output file is the original filename with ".out" appended. The invokation of `process_file` gets backgrounded and sent to job control. Looks dandy, right?

Except that I noticed that some files are not quite correctly handled.

I noticed that the file reported to be processed by `process_file` is always reported to be `/dev/fd/63`, even for separate simultaneous instances of `process_file`. On the other hand, when I separately copy or decompress the file to a temporary and pass the name of the temporary file to `process_file`, execution occurs normally and all files appear to be correctly handled.

I wanted to avoid creating a temporary file, particularly with regards to touching the disk (performance) and needing to clean up (remove) the temporary file after processing; having this problem hinders that. So I'm curious if there's some sort of race condition on the name of the pseudofile for the substituted process pipeline? Or is there something about process substitution or job control which I seem to misunderstand?

For reference, I'm using
Ubuntu Server 14.04, linux 3.19.0-59
Bash 4.3.11
gzip 1.6

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of digging and might be able to point you in the right direction.

Apparently, /dev/fd/63 is a standard file descriptor used by process_file.  So when you run multiple instances of process_file, it tries to send everything through this file descriptor.  You are probably creating a conflict or race condition as you suspect.

This page [file descriptors and bash shell scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13724/file-descriptors-shell-scripting) and this page [redirection_tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial)  have examples on redirecting outputs.

You probably need to modify process_file to create unique file descriptors or lock the descriptor while it is being used.

Comment: From my understanding, the file descriptor is created by Bash though